# How I can get order details and checkout details on my email woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, elementor

I have to collect order details and checkout details on my email account on clicking the place an order button in woocommerce and redirect them to home page without paying any order fee. I'm using the elementor with WC.
[image]

// Getting an instance of the order object

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
```

//Loop through them, you can get all the relevant data:

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
}
```

```
`
```

Comment: you only want to collect the order and customer information in your email without any payment for the order and redirect the customer to homepage after that?

Comment: yes, exactly. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default payment gateway in woocommerce without payment(ex:- COD).

you can hook into thank-you page using hook `woocommerce_thankyou`. then get the order object and relevent inforamtion and send this information using wp_mail() to your email then redirect the user to homepage.

for order information check out this blog.
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Use below code and if you need a customized email template.

**UPDATE 1.**

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'zillion_order_mail_and_redirect', 10, 1);
function zillion_order_mail_and_redirect($order_id)
{
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $url = home_url();

    $to = 'sendto@example.com';
    $subject = 'Order Info';
    $body = '';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    $body .= $order->get_formatted_order_total();

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    wp_safe_redirect($url);
    exit;
}
```

wp_mail() reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

**UPDATE 2:-**

You can add your email using  `woocommerce_email_headers` hook to get a copy of the email is being sent to the customer.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'zillion_order_mail_and_redirect', 10, 1);
function zillion_order_mail_and_redirect($order_id)
{
    $url = home_url();
    wp_safe_redirect($url);
    exit;
}

function zillion_hook_headers( $headers, $id, $order ) {
    // The order ID | Compatibility with WC version +3
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

    $your_email = '<example@gmail.com>';
    $headers .= "To: Order Num $order_id $your_email";
    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'zillion_hook_headers', 10, 3);
```

Comment: what if I use this whole code in the function.php file?
( https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/ )

Comment: you can try out this code in function.php but right now you will get only total amount of order in email.

this is an example code that i've posted above you can add the order information ( use reference blog for order object ) to email body and format the email body including html then `wp_mail()` will send the output to your given email  `$to`.

Comment: Hi, Sorry to bother you. I am not getting emails. I have set the payment gate ( Cash on Delivery ).
Here is the code I'm using:

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'zillion_order_mail_and_redirect', 10, 1);
function zillion_order_mail_and_redirect($order_id)
{
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $url = home_url('home');

    $to = 'ansarilast0@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Order Info';
    $body = '';

    $body .= $order->get_formatted_order_total();

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);
    wp_safe_redirect($url);
    exit;
}

Comment: it is working and tested. i've added the mail header so you can put html in email body. check your spam box email or check mail configuration on wordpress.

Comment: Yeah, I got spam emails but didn't not the order and checkout values. Below is the HTML that I'm getting through my email, where and in which email body I should put this?

( <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>200.00</bdi></span> )

Comment: i've edited the code above and added mail header to support html. you can try it out and  add other information as you want.

Comment: Gotcha Here is the SS of the email that I am getting right now ( https://paste.pics/d699c5943bd78a1b73681667f09a6dcd ).

This is the order I have placed ( https://paste.pics/a5e8d839b3d461e383d948d79ddcae7c ) and I want to get the order details with product name, quantity, products amount, customer email, and phone number like attached in the screenshot.
I really appreciate your precious time.

Comment: check the update 2 answer and try out the code then let me know.